# How to get not filled pageProperties

Tags: java, aem

I get the Page properties as follow:

```
 PageManager pageManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(PageManager.class);
 ValueMap pageProperties = pageManager.getPage(currentPagePath).getProperties();
```

Now these are only the page properties, which are filled in the page properties dialog. How to get all properties, which can be found in the page properties Dialog of some page?

Answer (score 0):

The properties that are not authored doesn't get saved in the content, unless there is any default value that has been specified for that particular field. One way of identifying is to check whether the particular key exists in your valuemap or not.

```
ValueMap pageProperties = pageManager.getPage(currentPagePath).getProperties();
if(pageProperties.get("property_name") == null) {
    //It has not been authored
}
```